# What happens exactly when we commit?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc, connection

I'm trying to understand what happens exactly when we commit

```
Connection conn=new Connection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStaement("insert statement 1");
ps.executeUpdate();
PreparedStatement ps2=connection.prepareStaement("insert statement 2");
ps2.executeUpdate();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

How will these 2 prepared statement reach the database?

Will they be combined in one database call? Or will they be inserted separately?
My impression is that they will be on one call to the database. The database receives something like:

```
START TRANSACTION
insert statement 1
insert statement 2
COMMIT
```

Also, how is the previous different from this one, how many calls happen on this one:

```
Connection conn=new Connection();
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
PreparedStatement ps=connection.prepareStaement("insert statement ?");
ps.setString(1,"1");
ps.addBatch();
ps.setString(1,"2");
ps.addBatch();
ps.executeBatch();
conn.commit();
conn.close();
```

Comment: They will be two calls. You can try this by causing the first insert to fail (i.e. insert a duplicate primary key or something)

Comment: From [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html): _Makes all changes made since the previous commit/rollback permanent and releases any database locks currently held by this Connection object_. As yourself have tested, there's only one transaction but the updates will be done command by command.

Comment: Since `executeUpdate()` is return an update count, indicating how many records were updated by the statement, how could it do that if it doesn't execute the statement until you call commit? --- `ps.executeUpdate()` and `ps2.executeUpdate()` and `conn.commit()` are 3 separate calls to the database.

Comment: The entire point of a batch is to collect statements to be executed together, to save of turn-around time to the database, so what do you think happens? The `ps.executeBatch()` and `conn.commit()` are 2 separate calls to the database.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from connection/disconnection, there are 5 database calls in the first scenario (prepare, execute, prepare, execute, commit), and 3 in the second (prepare, execute, commit). Actually this is a little biaised : for the examples to be comparable, you would need to run the same statement twice in the first scenario, hence saving one prepare. Also, as commented by [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5221149/andreas), some drivers might not issue a database call for prepare, and instead combine it with the first execute.

Anyway, conceptually, there is **one less database call in the second scenario** than in the first.

Transactions are a **server-side** functionality. When using transactions, changes to the database are visible to the session that performs them only. When a `COMMIT` is called, they become permanent, and visible to other users. On the other hand, the owning session can choose to `ROLLBACK`, which basically means : I definitively give up the changes that I have done since my last `COMMIT`. You can see that each of your code snippets happens in a single database transaction. From this perspective, they are not different.

Each call from the client to the server requires one network roundtrip, which can be expensive when running lots of small operations (say, a bunch of `INSERT`s). This is where **batches** come into play : they allow multiple operations to be executed in a single call to the database. In this regard, the second code snippet may scale better, as it will always perform the same number of database calls, no matter the number of records to process.

Comment: "Prepare" may or may not be a database call, that is entirely up to the JDBC driver. Since calls are expensive, most JDBC drivers will defer any actual preparation until the first execute, so the prepare and execute can be combined into a since call. So I will disagree with you and say that first scenarios is 3 calls, and second is 2 calls.

Comment: @Andreas : yes, agreed, I edited my post to mention that. It does not change the overall logic of my answer though.

Comment: @GMB  what is execute and what is commit? does "execute" call insert records on the db? my understanding is no records inserted till "commit". or do we send the transaction in multiple calls ie; call for start transaction, call for execute, call for commit?  Thanks a lot

Comment: @super7egazi : yes execute is a call to the database. Records get inserted but are only visible to the owning session, until COMMIT is called (or ROLLBACK).